# Exception when calling DefaultApi->flightInspirationSearch: [400] Error connecting to the API

Tags: php, error-handling, amadeus

I am trying to get started with `amadeus sandbox travel api` , and just getting started with `api` docs

```
  <?php
require_once(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');

$api_instance = new Swagger\Client\Api\DefaultApi();
$apikey = "jJtGVQ********************RONJZq1"; // string | API Key provided for your account, to identify you for API access. Make sure to keep this API key secret.
$origin = "NYC"; // string | <a href=\"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Air_Transport_Association_airport_code\">IATA code</a> of the city from which the traveler will depart. See the location and airport interfaces for more information.
$destination = "LAX"; // string | <a href=\"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Air_Transport_Association_airport_code\">IATA code</a> of the city to which the traveler is going
$departure_date = "2017-12-16--2017-12-26"; // string | Range of dates between which the traveler could depart. Dates are specified in the <a href=\"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601\">ISO 8601</a> yyyy-MM-dd date format. Ranges are inclusive and ranges of months will apply from the start to the end of the month. If just a single date is specified, only that date will be searched. By default, the date range starts today and applies up to 361 in the future is applied. Past dates are generally not supported, future dates should be in the next 361 days, although results start to become sparse after about 6 months in the future, as airlines may still be defining their schedules. The default is to search all future dates available.
$one_way = false; // bool | When set to true, the query will be for a single trip from the origin to the destination. When this parameter is not provided, or is set to false, the query is for a round trip from the origin to the destination and back again.
$duration = "1--15"; // string | The allowed duration or range of durations of the trip, in days. This parameter must not be set if the one-way parameter is set to true.
$direct = false; // bool | Limit the search to results that do not require the passenger to change plane?
$max_price = "100000"; // string | Maximum price of trips to find in the result set, in the currency specified for this origin and destination pair in the cache contents spreadsheet. So, for example, if the origin is NYC, and the max price is 400, this means 400 USD. If the origin is PAR, and the max price is 400, this means 400 EUR. By default, no limit is applied
$aggregation_mode = ""; // string | Specifies the granularity of results to be found. DESTINATION is the default and finds one result per city. COUNTRY finds one result per country, DAY finds on result for every day in the date range, WEEK finds one result for every week in the date range. Note that specifying a small granularity but a large search scope may result in a huge output. For some very large outputs, the API may refuse to provide a result.

try {
    $result = $api_instance->flightInspirationSearch($apikey, $origin, $destination, $departure_date, $one_way, $duration, $direct, $max_price, $aggregation_mode);
    print_r($result);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Exception when calling DefaultApi->flightInspirationSearch: ', $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

this is the sample code I am using to perform search 
but it is giving me an error

Exception when calling `DefaultApi`

> > flightInspirationSearch: [400] Error connecting to the API (https://api.sandbox.amadeus.com/v1.2/flights/inspiration-search?apikey=jJt*************************JZq1&origin=NYC&destination=LAX&departure_date=2017-12-16--2017-12-26&one-way=0&duration=1--15&direct=0&max_price=100000&aggregation_mode=)

I would really appreciate if some one could tell me why am I getting this error , I am actually using `xampp` for locally testing on a windows machine with php > 7.0

I think it is because I am missing dependencies but help is needed 
thanks

.php_cs

```
│   .travis.yml
│   autoload.php
│   composer.json
│   composer.lock
│   git_push.sh
│   index.php
│   phpunit.xml.dist
│   README.md
│   tree
│   tree.txt
│   
├───docs
│   ├───Api
│   │       DefaultApi.md
│   │       
│   └───Model
│           
│           
├───lib
│   │   
│   │   
│   ├───Api
│   │       │   │       
│   └───Model
│           
├───test
│   ├───Api
│   │   │       
│   └───Model
│           
│           
└───vendor
```

Comment: Did you check this api url via commandline or browser? May be an ip restriction?

Comment: @mim thanks for replying , i figured out what the problem was my manually putting the url in browser , it turns out , it was treating false as a boolean , but wanted to have string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <?php
require_once(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');

$api_instance = new Swagger\Client\Api\DefaultApi();
$apikey = "jJtGVQ********************RONJZq1"; // string | API Key provided for your account, to identify you for API access. Make sure to keep this API key secret.
$origin = "NYC"; // string | <a href=\"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Air_Transport_Association_airport_code\">IATA code</a> of the city from which the traveler will depart. See the location and airport interfaces for more information.
$destination = "LAX"; // string | <a href=\"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Air_Transport_Association_airport_code\">IATA code</a> of the city to which the traveler is going
$departure_date = "2017-12-16--2017-12-26"; // string | Range of dates between which the traveler could depart. Dates are specified in the <a href=\"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601\">ISO 8601</a> yyyy-MM-dd date format. Ranges are inclusive and ranges of months will apply from the start to the end of the month. If just a single date is specified, only that date will be searched. By default, the date range starts today and applies up to 361 in the future is applied. Past dates are generally not supported, future dates should be in the next 361 days, although results start to become sparse after about 6 months in the future, as airlines may still be defining their schedules. The default is to search all future dates available.
$one_way = false; // bool | When set to true, the query will be for a single trip from the origin to the destination. When this parameter is not provided, or is set to false, the query is for a round trip from the origin to the destination and back again.
$duration = "1--15"; // string | The allowed duration or range of durations of the trip, in days. This parameter must not be set if the one-way parameter is set to true.
$direct = false; // bool | Limit the search to results that do not require the passenger to change plane?
$max_price = "100000"; // string | Maximum price of trips to find in the result set, in the currency specified for this origin and destination pair in the cache contents spreadsheet. So, for example, if the origin is NYC, and the max price is 400, this means 400 USD. If the origin is PAR, and the max price is 400, this means 400 EUR. By default, no limit is applied
$aggregation_mode = ""; // string | Specifies the granularity of results to be found. DESTINATION is the default and finds one result per city. COUNTRY finds one result per country, DAY finds on result for every day in the date range, WEEK finds one result for every week in the date range. Note that specifying a small granularity but a large search scope may result in a huge output. For some very large outputs, the API may refuse to provide a result.

try {
    $result = $api_instance->flightInspirationSearch($apikey, $origin, $destination, $departure_date, $one_way, $duration, $direct, $max_price, $aggregation_mode);
    print_r($result);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Exception when calling DefaultApi->flightInspirationSearch: ', $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

just change the `$one_way = false;` to `$one_way = "false";` basically it was not taking boolean but takes string as a parameter even though the api say boolean , and also make similar changes to `$direct`

Answer (score 0):

Check if `NYC` represents a valid airport code (seems to me that no).

Comment: NYC is a valid IATA code , thanks , i have solved the problem , i think the api itself have some underlining bugs , but i changed 0 to false and now it is working

Answer (score 0):

I would like to precise that there is no bug in the API, I have just tested using an http client, query parameters **one_way** and **direct** are expecting boolean type and not a string, if you try "true" or "false" values, you will receive a bad request response error (HTTPsatus = 400). You can try it yourself using the [shooter](https://sandbox.amadeus.com/travel-innovation-sandbox/apis/get/flights/inspiration-search) of the API.

The issue is most likely in your PHP method that builds the final http query, there should be a bad transformation from boolean to string, hence the 400 HTTP error you have received.